# Mobile website analytics solution

Tags: mobile, analytics

I have my website's mobile version. I need get statistics about users visiting my mob website, unique visits, page views and so on. I'm looking for tool, similar like Google Analytics, but for mobile websites. Google Analytics is not the solution, because it is based on JavaScript. Most mobile device browsers doesn't support JavaScript. Mobile analytics tools lets users to add 1x1 px size image instead JavaScript tracking code.

[Bango.com](http://bango.com/) is something what I'm looking for. But it is too expensive for me. €39 per month is too much for non commercial websites.

Do you know any other **free or less expensive mobile analytics solutions** for websites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I´m using [Admob Analytics](http://analytics.admob.com/), it´s free. You could use [google analytics](http://mobiforge.com/forum/running/analytics/google-analytics-mobile) [without js](http://www.ianlewis.org/en/title).

Answer (score 1):

I use Motally and I love it. It's free and it was built specifically for mobile, so it's a lot more accurate than Google Analytics and the like. I really like that it provides all the standard stats and you can also do stuff like internal search tracking, funnel analysis and a/b testing.

www.motally.com

/* This site no longer seems to exist */

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using Google Analytics for Mobiles: http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/web/

This allows tracking on mobile websites that receive traffic from phones that do not support JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I find that using the apache access logs (assuming your using apache server) along with a free log analyzer serves my needs quite well for mobile analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed; you can just analyse the stats with something like awstats.